# How can I change the color of the notification icon in a google chrome extension (creator of extension)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, notifications, icons

I set up notifications in my chrome extension, and it is a bright red notification in the bottom right of the icon (1, 2, 3, etc.)

Looks like this:
[image]

I would like to make it a green notification or maybe another color in the top right instead.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this doesn't look like a [Google Chrome notification](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html), I'm assuming you're talking about the [browser action badge](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#badge).

You can set the background color of the badge with the [`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setBadgeBackgroundColor) method. For example, for a green background:

```
chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: "#00FF00"});
```

where `"#00FF00"` is the [hex triplet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Hex_triplet) representing your color.

The location of the badge can't be changed, so you can't put in the top right corner.

Comment: The method takes an object, not a string. Use `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:'#00F00'});`. If the OP really wants to get the counter at a different location, s/he can paint the button on a canvas and use [`chrome.browserAction.setIcon`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#method-setIcon) to paint the result. Unless s/he has a very good reason to want this, I advise against doing this, because users expect the counter to be located at a consistent location, i.e. the bottom.

Comment: I've edited my answer to correct my mistake. I didn't think of using a canvas, that's an interesting idea.

Comment: yes, the action badge is precisely what I was referring to. After waiting a while for a response i did some research and found exactly what you said, `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor` but I didn't know I could use the hex code for a color, which is useful. Basically I reverse engineered another major extension that uses notifications to find out what they did, and that's what I discovered. However, I still need to know about positioning and special styling of the badge; i.e. put the badge in the top left of icon; and having a border around the badge. So how can I do that?

Comment: @Rob, good idea. I'll accept this answer cause it does have the solution for changing the background color. Hopefully someone can tell me how to make the canvas work.